# ASP.Net MVC3 - custom model binding, the default model binder, value types and the [Required] attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, model-binding

My action takes a class property which is bound by the default model binder:

```
public ActionResult MyControllerAction(MyModelClass model) { ...
```

The class uses several non-standard value types, such as MongoDB's `ObjectId` value type, which is of course non-nullable.

If I create a custom model binder for the ObjectId type (easy enough to do) and add it to the in `Application_Start` like so:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(ObjectId), new ObjectIdModelBinder());
```

... it is ignored by the default model binder, which only seems to apply to model values passed in as an argument directly to the action.

On top of this, I can't get seem to get the `[Required]` attribute to recognise the default (not specified) value as having not been supplied.

So in a nut shell:

- How do I get the default model binder to use the registered custom model binders to parse a model's properties?
- How do I get `[Required]` to recognise the `default` value of that property as not having been specified?

Or -- is there something already out there which already handles all of this which I can download and use in my project?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to *not* use these fancy types in your view models?  IMO, the view models should be ultra simple and any translation to/from more sophisticated types should happen in the controller.

Comment: yeah sure, and that's what I was doing, except for the fact that every single action that takes an ID value requires the same snippet of code to parse and validate an ID value. I figured putting it in a model binder would be easier. I figured it out just now though, so I'll post and answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out already:

- `DefaultModelBinder` *does* use any specified custom model binders, but only if the value is actually specified in the submitted values
- The `[Required]` attribute is basically shorthand for "not null", and therefore does work if the property is specified as nullable, i.e. in my case, `ObjectId?` will trip up the attribute if no value is specified.

Here's a good blog post I found that explains some of this stuff: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html